# "Correct" Way to Show New Controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm designing a small helper utility with a simple UI. I'm working off the following mockup:

[image]

The execution flow is meant to be as follows:

1. User clicks "Other" radio button.
2. A textbox is presented and user is prompted to write in a response.

My question is: What is the "correct" way to achieve the UI change from the picture on the left to the picture on the right? My options seem to be either create a unique window for each, or have all of the controls on the same window and just play with the visibility of the controls.

Comment: DataTemplates are another way

Comment: For such simple scenarios, you may well be off with a simple Click event handler, where you toggle `Visibility` of the two panels.

Comment: You can do it lots of different ways (so, the question is too broad). But I wouldn't go so far as to create a whole new window. Either define both layouts in XAML and change visibility according to the radio group selection, or use two different view models for each scenario, with a template for each, and switch the view model if/when the "Other" radio button is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "correct" way really. It all depends on your requirements.

If you want the new screen to show up in a new window, then create a new window. If you want it to show up in the same window and simply replace the previous screen with the radiobuttons, then toggle the `Visibility` property of the individual controls or the parent `Panel`, preferably using a view model that has either `bool` or `Visibility` source properties that you have bound to in your view.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to nest all of the "controls to hide" within a parent grid or stackpanel. I was worried about keeping track of the visibility of multiple independent controls - this solves that. Thanks!